Save Screen for no reload SwiftUI on Custom Tabview
I do a custom tab View using Buttons and @State on the principal Struct but when I change of screen the previous screen don't save the state of that always reset the screen, a new instance is created when change of screen I dont search this for example when scroll on a scrollview of any view on tab view and change the view for another HomeView() and change for SearchView() when return to HomeView() it restarted
struct PrincipalTabViewNV: View {
    @State var index = 0
    @State private var destination: Destination?    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack{
                    if self.index == 0{
                        HomeView()
                    }else if self.index == 1{
                        SearchView()
                    }else if self.index == 2{
                        ProfileView(destination: $destination)
                    }else if self.index == 3{
                        SavedView()
                    }
                }.padding(.bottom,-25)

                HStack{
                    ZStack{
                        CustomTabs(index: self.$index)
                            .offset(y:30)
                        
                        
                        //add button
                        Button(action: {
                            self.index = 1
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 50,height: 50)
                        .background(Color.orange)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.4), radius: 20)
                        .offset(y:-8)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden)
        .background(Color.white)
        }.fullScreenCover(item: $destination){ dest in
            switch dest {
            case .restart:
                ContentView()
            case .welcome:
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct CustomTabs: View {
    @Binding var index: Int
    var body: some View{
        ZStack {
            HStack(){
                //home button
                VStack {
                    if self.index == 0 {
                        Line().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: 30,height: 2)
                            .offset(y:-15)
                            .padding(0)
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.index = 0
                    }){
                     Image("home")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25,height: 25)
                    }
                    .colorMultiply(self.index == 0 ? Color.orange.opacity(1): Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                .offset(y: self.index == 0 ? -7: 0)
                }
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)

                //search
                VStack {
                    if self.index == 1 {
                        Line().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: 30,height: 2)
                            .offset(y:-15)
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                        self.index = 1
                    }){
                     Image("search")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25,height: 25)
                    }
                    .colorMultiply(self.index == 1 ? Color.orange.opacity(1): Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                .offset(y: self.index == 1 ? -7: 0)
                }

                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                //profile
                VStack {
                    if self.index == 2 {
                        Line().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: 30,height: 2)
                            .offset(y:-15)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.index = 2
                    }){
                     Image("profile")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20,height: 25)
                    }
                    .colorMultiply(self.index == 2 ? Color.orange.opacity(1): Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                .offset(y: self.index == 2 ? -7: 0)
                }

                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)

                //saved
                VStack {
                    if self.index == 3 {
                        Line().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: 30,height: 2)
                            .offset(y:-15)
                            .padding(0)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.index = 3
                    }){
                     Image("saved")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25,height: 25)
                    }
                    .colorInvert()
                    .colorMultiply(self.index == 3 ? Color.orange.opacity(1): Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                .offset(y: self.index == 3 ? -7: 0)
                }

                
            }.padding()
                .padding(.horizontal,20)
                .padding(.bottom,15)
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(CShape()).shadow(radius: 2)
        }
    }
}

I tried to dont create a new instance or screen for no reset the state of the view completely

You should design your views so that they are "disposable". The state should not be held in the view itself if you need to be able to create a new instance and have it reflect that state.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@Paulw11 can you explain in code ?

Not really. Separation of app state from view state is a core part of SwiftUI. SwiftUI views should be lightweight and disposable. You need to have enough information in your app state so that when the view is recreated, it shows as required. You haven't explained what state you are losing.

The entire state, in itself, is not a specific state but rather the screen will be recreated from 0 and that is what I don't want :(
